# Pass integer array from view to controller without ajax / javascript

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc

My view is strongly typed to a *Product* class. I want to pass the ID of this product to a method in the controller in an integer array like this:

```
@Html.Action("SomeAction", "controller", new int?[] {@Model.ID})
```

In my controller I have a method like:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(int?[] IDs) {

}
```

But this does not work and I always get null in my controller. So how do I pass an integer array from the view to the controller (without ajax / javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
@Html.Action("SomeAction", "controller", new { IDs = new [] { @Model.ID } })
```

The last argument to `Action(...)` is an object, the property names of which should match the parameter names to your action.  In your case, the action takes a single parameter `IDs`, so your object needs to have an `IDs` property.